# Identifying blocks (of variable length) of numbers that must occur in a consecutive sequence

Tags: python, list, indexing, pattern-matching

Problem Statement: 
An array is accepted if and only if it has the following structure:

- First a1 elements equal 1.
- Next a2 elements equal 2.
- Next a3 elements equal 3.
- Next a4 elements equal 4.
- Next a5 elements equal 5.
- Next a6 elements equal 6.
- Next a7 elements equal 7.

Where:

- a(i) can be any non-zero positive integer.
- There are no other elements in array.

Even though the algorithm for this problem seems pretty easy to implement, I am having some difficulty with the code. Here is what I have written.

```
print("Enter list: ")
arr = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print(arr)
i = 0

if arr[0] == 1:  # to check whether input starts with a 1. 
    if arr[i] == 1:  #If next number is also 1, then
        while arr[i] == 1:  #while numbers are equal to 1, increment i
            i = i + 1
            if arr[i] == 2: #If next number is 2, then
                while arr[i] == 2: #same procedure as above ... and so on
                    i = i + 1
                    if arr[i] == 3:
                        while arr[i] == 3:
                            i = i + 1
                            if arr[i] == 4:
                                while arr[i] == 4:
                                    i = i + 1
                                    if arr[i] == 5:
                                        while arr[i] == 5:
                                            i = i + 1
                                            if arr[i] == 6:
                                                while arr[i] == 6:
                                                    i = i + 1
                                                    if arr[i] == 7:
                                                        while arr[i] == 7:
                                                            i = i + 1
                                                        if arr[-1] == 7: #to check if last number is a 7
                                                            print("Accepted")
                                                        else:
                                                            print("not")
                                                    else:
                                                        print("not")
                                            else:
                                                print("not")
                                    else:
                                        print("not")
                            else:
                                print("not")
                    else:
                        print("not")
            else:
                print("not")
    else:
        print("not")
else:
    print("not")
```

I seem to be getting some kind of indexing error where it says:

```
   while arr[i] == 7:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand why I am encountering this error. As far as I can tell, I am not exceeding the list index.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: I'd have to say that this looks like highly redundant code. I am pretty sure you can simplify all of this in just a few lines. To give you a hint, the number you are expecting to find correlates very close to the position in the array you expect it to be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/how-to-prevent-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-java)

Comment: Dupe target is for Java, but the solution isn't all that different in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def is_accepted(arr):
    return arr[0] == 1 and all(arr[i] -1 == arr[i-1] or arr[i] == arr[i-1] for i in range(1, len(arr)))

print(is_accepted([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Second List:

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7]
print(is_accepted(s))
```

Output:

```
False
```

Last input:

```
s = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7]
print(is_accepted(s))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: `Enter list:   
1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 5 6 7  
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7]  
True`  
It shows True for the wrong pattern too.

Comment: @SakshiJain When I run that list you just posted, the output is False.

Comment: It doesn't work on redundant numbers. Say if I input a string `s = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7]` according to the problem statement, it is a valid input. But the program says otherwise.

Comment: @SakshiJain So you are saying that redundant numbers are acceptable in this problem?

Comment: I think the solution to that would be adding an if statement like `if arr[i] == arr[i-1] or arr[i] == arr[i-1]+1` instead of your original condition.

Comment: Yes. It says in the problem statement that a(i) elements equal to number. Where a(i) could be any non-zero number.

Answer (score 0):

A fun exercise in recursion.

Write cases the following conditions:

- list is empty
- first item of list less than last_checked as a short-circuit
- match recursively.

```
def match(lst, last_checked=1):
  if lst == []: return True # base case

  if lst[0] < last_checked:
    return False

  return True and match(lst[1:], lst[0])
```